# Multiple concurrent event call for flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, events, state, bloc

I am trying to show map and details in one page. For that I am making two event call(one for map second for details) from same bloc. But, before first event call finishes, second event fires up. Because of which I am unable to capture last state of my first event. I wanted to know if I can fire multiple event concurrently or not. If yes, what is the process. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`flutter_bloc` uses simple `Stream` of events which mapped to states with `Stream.asyncExpand` function witch help bloc to emit zero or more states

> asyncExpand Transforms each element into a sequence of asynchronous events

You can fire events and they will be handled in FIFO manner

Comment: the best way is kindly share with example so anyone can understand it